# What should be passed as the objectName when throwing an ObjectDisposedException?

Tags: .net, idisposable, objectdisposedexception

When implementing IDisposable, I undertand that every method that shouldn't be called after the object's been disposed should throw the `ObjectDisposedException`.  But what is the standard for the name object that should be passed to the exception's constructor?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I believe the recommended practice is to throw the following:

```
throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
```

Or including the check, these two lines of code at the top of each method that needs it (obviously not the `Dispose` method itself):

```
if (this.disposed)
    throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
```

Might even be helpful to refactor this into a tiny method for usability.

Comment: Also, please see this question and my answer for general guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668440/handling-objectdisposedexception-correctly-in-an-idisposable-class-hierarchy

Answer (score 15):

Even the .NET Framework itself isn't very consistent here.

David M. Kean (former developer on the FxCop team at Microsoft) added a comment to the [MSDN documentation for the ObjectDisposedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The typical usage of this type is something like the following:
>
> ```
> [C#]
> private void CheckDisposed()
> {
>     throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
> }
> ```

Comment: I missed it. Mut learn to read the comments in the documentation also.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: The comment was obviously removed from the .NET 4-version of the page. I fixed the link above so it refers to the .NET 3.5-version which includes the quoted comment.

Comment: Might as well do ``throw new ObjectDisposedException(ToString());``

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a standard for that, I would return the type of the object along with the string content of a unique identifying field (a 'Primary Key' of sorts).