# Common way for IDisposable type throw System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Am not sure if am repeating this question. 
For Code violation for throwing System.ObjectDisposedException. Statndard solution is to have below function call for each function

```
private void CheckDisposed()
{
    throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
}
```

more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964521/1481690

Instead of calling this method in each function.How can i make this happen for all functions globally like in single place across application. Am using Mvc5.

Comment: Sadly, you will have to have to do exactly that :-(

Comment: Note that you don't have to, and in general should't, throw ObjectDisposedException in *every* method call.  You only need to do so if the method depends on the unmanaged resource that has been disposed.

Comment: @Joe Am having a simple MVC function with CURD operation. But gendarme is showing the violation if i don't throw ObjectDisposedException . and it is happy if i have that line. Am i doing wrong ?