# Does Asp.net MVC ActionResult implements IDisposable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gendarme

Am getting **gendarme** issues on my MVC 5 Application in all the public methods stating

**"A method of an IDisposable type does not throw System.ObjectDisposedException."**

As far as i know most of the .net resources(Managed resources) by default implement  IDisposable.

Whether the MVC ActionResult doesn't implement IDisposable ? or the gendarme  is showing it wrongly ?

More on [gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/gendarme/rules/exceptions/#useobjectdisposedexceptionrule) issue and similar conversation Thread [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1491426.aspx?Why%20doesn%20t%20ActionResult%20implement%20IDisposable%20)

If i apply the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964496/what-should-be-passed-as-the-objectname-when-throwing-an-objectdisposedexception/1964521#1964521) to all the functions gendarme is happy. So am little confused !!

Answer (score -1):

MVC ActionResult is not derived from any class/interface. ActionResult is basically an abstract class.