# Using ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#

When implementing the Dispose pattern the object's properties should throw ObjectDisposedException after the object has been disposed.

It seem like a lot of repeated code if every property and method has a line of code at the beginning of the setter and getter to throw that exception even it its just ThrowIfDisposed().  If you have 40 properties that's 80 repeated lines. In a large class it can add up very fast.

I haven't been able to find a better way so it seem like that's just the way it is but I thought I would ask.  Is there a better way?

Comment: The disposable pattern was a .NET 1.x mistake, very hard to get rid of.  Fixed thoroughly in .NET 2.0 with the critical finalizers implemented in the SafeHandle classes.  The only remaining use for the pattern is when the base class implements it, forcing you to deal with it as well.  Peppering your code with throws does not make it better, you simply rely on the base class to throw the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I'll have to look into the SafeHandle class.  I never liked the disposable pattern and would love to find a better replacement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have 40 properties in a single class then you probably have a design issue, but moving on... It really depends on the specific use-case, but you should only throw the ObjectDisposedException if the property can't actually be resolved because the class has been disposed. To give a concrete example:

```
public class MyStream : IDisposable
{
    private string name;
    private Stream stream;

    public MyStream(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Stream = new FileStream(...);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public Stream Stream
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.IsDisposed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException();
            }

            return this.stream;
        }
    }

    private bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!this.IsDisposed)
        {
            this.IsDisposed = true;
            this.Stream.Dispose();
            this.Stream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the property `Stream` throws an exception because the underlying stream has been disposed, so it can't be used anymore. But `Name` has no reason to throw.
From there, in many cases, you can factorize your code so that access to the actual problematic property throws the exception:

```
public int Length
{
    get 
    {
        // Since we access the Stream property, the ObjectDisposedException
        // will be thrown when the class is disposed
        return this.Stream.Length;
    }
}
```

---

If you still have too many properties to decorate even after following this pattern, you can use libraries like [Fody](https://github.com/Fody) that allows you to inject a behavior at compilation time. Using it, you could make an attribute `[ThrowIfDisposed]` that you apply on properties as needed.

Comment: I agree that 40+ properties is a lot and normally it means too much was packed into a single class that should be broken up but sometimes it's the only way. Excel is an example. Working with it is what prompted my to ask this question. For instance, the Range class has 99 properties and 87 methods. Working with COM from .NET is a pain in the a**. Once the object has been disposed and all the excel resource freed any properties or methods that use excel will throw null pointer exceptions. It seem inelegant but maybe just allowing those null pointer exceptions is the solution in this case.

Comment: `ObjectDisposedException` has no public parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Check other topic: [Handling ObjectDisposedException correctly in an IDisposable class hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668440/handling-objectdisposedexception-correctly-in-an-idisposable-class-hierarchy)

You do not need to throw exception every time somebody access property of class that implements `:IDisposable`. It is only necessary, if You are accessing the object that must be disposed (e.g. write/read to files, accessing network sockets, ..). For all the other cases, You can just go with idea normal class.

Normally the objects/classes do not have this large number of properties as there is option to split them among more classes -> which will allow You to make only part of this `:IDisposable`, and the rest will be independent on the `IDisposable` class.